# Shell script to search for a pattern in a file using if else

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, tcsh

This is my script, I want to find a pattern in a file. I know the exit status of `grep -q '<Pattern>' '<file>' && echo $?` is 0 if pattern is found. But I am getting **if: Expression Syntax** error.

```
 if ( (grep -q '<Pattern>' '<file>' && echo $?)==0  ) then
 echo "Pattern found"
 else
 echo "Pattern not found"
 endif
```

Comment: I don't know tcsh, but in bash and POSIX sh, you'd just do `if grep -q '<pattern>' '<file>'; then`.

Comment: I'd do that in `tcsh` as well: `sh -c 'if grep -q "<Pattern>" "<file>"; then ... '` :)

Comment: BTW, the `shell` tag is generally focused on POSIX-family shells; better to stick to `csh` and `tcsh` tags here, to avoid pulling in a bunch of folks who consider any use of csh [severely](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) [misguided](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
if ( { grep -q '<Pattern>' '<file>' } ) then
 echo "Pattern found"
else
 echo "Pattern not found"
endif
```

Note the curly braces around command and the spaces between braces and command.

See the [man tcsh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh), **Expressions**:

> **Command exit status**
>
> Commands can be executed in expressions and their exit status returned
>   by enclosing them in braces ('{}'). Remember that the braces should be
>   separated from the words of the command by spaces.